# Generic list in abstract method

Tags: java, android, generics, abstract-class

I have a Base abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class BaseModel {
//some code
}
```

I am extending it with another Base abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class BaseChildParentModel extends BaseModel {

    public abstract <E extends BaseModel> List<E> getChildren();

    public abstract <E extends BaseModel> List<E> createChildList();

    public void addChild(BaseModel child) {
        List<BaseModel> children = getChildren();
        if (children == null)
            children = createChildList();
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

My last class extend `BaseChildParentModel` like this:

```
public class Subject extends BaseChildParentModel {

 //some fields

    public ArrayList<Subject> ChildSubjects;

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> getChildren() {
        return ChildSubjects;
    }

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> createChildList() {
        ChildSubjects = new ArrayList<>();
        return ChildSubjects;
    }
}
```

On compile i get following error:

```
Error:(52, 16) error: incompatible types
required: List<E>
found:    ArrayList<Subject>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends BaseModel declared in method <E>getChildren()
```

and

```
Error:(58, 16) error: incompatible types
required: List<E>
found:    ArrayList<Subject>
where E is a type-variable:
E extends BaseModel declared in method <E>createChildList()
```

What is the my fault?

Comment: Try changing public ArrayList<Subject> ChildSubjects; to public List<Subject> ChildSubjects;

Comment: I change it but get same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public abstract class Subject extends BaseChildParentModel {
    public List<Subject> ChildSubjects;

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> getChildren() {
        return (List<E>) ChildSubjects;
    }

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> createChildList() {
        ChildSubjects = new ArrayList<>();
        return (List<E>) ChildSubjects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Errors cleared and compile is success. but i get unchecked cast warning. i am completing code for checking it in run time. if its OK, i will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

//try this code

```
public class Subject extends BaseChildParentModel {

 //some fields

    public ArrayList<Subject> ChildSubjects;

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> getChildren() {
        return ((E)ChildSubjects);
    }

    @Override
    public <E extends BaseModel> List<E> createChildList() {
        ChildSubjects = new ArrayList<>();
        return ((E)ChildSubjects);
    }
}
```

//typecast before return the data. 
it might be helpful for you.